# How to understand that content loaded?

Tags: reactjs, iframe-resizer

I use library [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/example/frame.content.html). So, I created react - component. There is any time while I am waitting for loading content in frame and I want to show user cirle-bar in this time. How to uderstand that loading is complete?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go through lifecycle of React.js

There are two life cycle methods

> **componentWillMount()** - gets called before the DOM is loaded.
>
> **componentDidMount()** - gets called after the DOM is loaded / component is rendered completely.

So you do

```
componentWillMount(){
 //show MyLoader
}

componentDidMount(){
  // hide MyLoader
}
```

see more - https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html

https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/post_mount_with_component_did_mount.html

Comment: Unfortunatly it's not correct, because componentDidMount() called after creating and render iframe-resizer. But, after that event, there is some actions 3-4 seconds to re-rendering and showing content.

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov, This is not correct, why? Did you have a look at the references I put here? This is what I do in my current application which works fine.